# Type definition for specific values of objects array

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following object array:

```
const shapes = [
    { name: 'circle', color: 'blue' },
    { name: 'square', size: 42 },
    { name: 'rectangle', color: 'blue' }
];

type ShapeName = typeof shapes[number]['name']; // ShapeName is type 'string' but I would want: 'circle'|'square'|'rectangle'
```

I would like to have a type "ShapeName" that contains the values of the **name** properties of my objects. However, attempting to do so just gives me the 'string' as type. Is there a way to narrow it down to **'circle'|'square'|'rectangle'**.

[TsPlayground example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWBDADgUwjAvDA2gKBkJgG8YxEBbVALhgHJgBLAJ2ABtU6AaGUNkZrToAjNgFdOMAL5cCRUuSpCIARzGJmnHhEYAvGjAAsAJmmyiJMpQN1NwKIjABzDt14h+g+qIl1peAF0Abjw8KABPNBgAZSQ0ADlrLBgItBAAMzg49BwwMQphVGYAnDpFTmCYAHoqmOyYRgxU1HpoZkZnP2ExWABJGAB3EDE2ABNBxyghJlZXAB86VXVNOgW7B2dXIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define an array of objects, it only makes sense that you may add more values to it later. TypeScript assumes this is the case and you may add more objects later... which may or may not have only mentioned three values for `name` attribute. Also, in general, TypeScript infers that `name` to be a `string` which is most commonly what you would want a object to be inferred as. So, normally `string` inference is a very good idea for the most of the cases.

To tell TypeScript that this is a fixed array, you need to use [Const Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). Which turns array literals into `readonly` tuples. Like this:

```ts
const shapes = [
  { name: "circle", color: "blue" },
  { name: "square", size: 42 },
  { name: "rectangle", color: "blue" },
] as const;

type ShapeName = typeof shapes[number]["name"];
// type ShapeName = "circle" | "square" | "rectangle"
```

Here is the TS Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/m029ow